# Silverlight ContentProperty on abstract class Panel

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Here is a hierarchy of my class `MyContainer`.  Notice that the `Panel` has a `Children` as well as `MyContainer`. Can I still use the `Children` from `Panel` as well?

What is the meaning of `[ContentProperty("Children", true)]`? The summary explains:

> Specifies which property of a class
>   can be interpreted to be the content
>   property when the class is parsed by a
>   XAML processor.

But I am not understanding what he means?

```
[ContentProperty("Children", true)]
public abstract class Panel : FrameworkElement
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the collection of child elements of the panel.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The collection of child objects. The default is an empty collection.
    public UIElementCollection Children { get; }
}

public class Canvas : Panel
{....}

public class MyContainer : Canvas
{

    public MyContainer();

    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> Children {get;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ContentProperty attribute means that the following two  elements are equivalent - the Children property of Canvas is the default content of the Canvas.

```
<Canvas>
    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
    <Button Content="World"/>
</Canvas>

<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Children>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
        <Button Content="World"/>
    </Canvas.Children>
</Canvas>
```